# Calculate price based on interval

Tags: php, math

The code has to be in PHP, how is this possible?

I want to calculate a price based on these principles:

0-50 = 3 pr unit.
50-100 = 2.5 pr unit.
100-150 = 2 pr unit.
150+ = 1.5 pr unit.

For example an order of 125 units would cost:

```
(50 * 3) + (50 * 2,5) + (25 * 2) = 325
```

I think this could be done with a while loop or maybe there is some function that can do it more easily?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is "gimme the codez".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function calculatePrice($numberOfUnits) {
    // Initialise price
    $price = 0;

    // Prices: amount for category => price for category
    // Starts with largest category
    $prices = array(150 => 1.5, 100 => 2, 50 => 2.5, 0 => 3);

    // Loop over price categories
    foreach($prices as $categoryAmount => $categoryPrice) {

        // Calculate the numbers that fall into the category
        $amount = $numberOfUnits - $categoryAmount;

        // If units fall into the category, add to the price
        // and calculate remaining units
        if($amount > 0) {
            $price += $amount*$categoryPrice;
            $numberOfUnits -= $amount;
        }
    }

    // Return the total price
    return $price;
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PPvdyB).

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 : You can make a loop and check if number is less or greater than a value (50,100...) to set unit price.

```
$value = 1000;
echo getPrice($value);

function getPrice($value)
{
    $price = 0;
    $prices = array(3,2.5,2,1.5);

    for ( $i = 1 ; $i <= $value ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $i < 50 ) $price += $prices[0];
        else if ( $i < 100 ) $price += $prices[1];
        else if ( $i < 150 ) $price += $prices[2];
        else $price += $prices[3];
    }

    return $price;    
}
```

Method 2 : You can calculate each price interval.

```
$value = 1000;
echo getPrice($value);

function getPrice($value)
{
    $price = 0;
    $prices = array(3,2.5,2,1.5);

    if ( $value > 150 )
        return $prices[0] * 50 + $prices[1] * 50 + $prices[2] * 50 + ( $value - 150 ) * $prices[3];

    if ( $value > 100 )
        return $prices[0] * 50 + $prices[1] * 50 + ( $value - 100 ) * $prices[2];

    if ( $value > 50 )
        return $prices[0] * 50 + ( $value - 50 ) * $prices[1];

    return $value * $prices[0]; 
}
```